# Scala's Option in domain class for REST API

Tags: scala

I'm not sure how I should design my domain classes when using Scala. Suppose I want to provide a REST API for managing books. When user creates a new book, ID of the book and an E-tag are not specified so I figured that I'll use Option type for these fields:

```
class Book(val id: Option[UUID], val name: String, val eTag: Option[String])
```

When a book is persisted, ID and E-Tag are generated, so after persisting `id` and `eTag` are always instances of `Some`. Working with persisted books is more difficult because of these `Option`s and this difficulty seems not right to me since I can be sure that they are `Some`s. Should I create another class, a `NonPersistedBook` without `id` and `eTag` fields and use its instances when users create a new book and get rid of `Options` from `Book`? When client updates a book it provides ID but doesn't provide an E-tag. Should I have another class for this case?

Comment: Yep, if a type is wrong, define another type.

Comment: @ChrisMartin What about code duplication? What about operations that NonPersistedBook, Book and UpdatedBook classes may share? Should these classes be related through inheritance or in other way?

Comment: I'd need example code to address specifically.

Comment: Take a look at the [Metarest](https://github.com/pathikrit/metarest) project. It addresses this exact problem.

Comment: @Vered: I guess that Metarest project solves this, and it looks like Chris Martin was also right. I think it would be cool to have this in a legitimate answer I could accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Metarest project](https://github.com/pathikrit/metarest) addresses this problem using Macros to generate RESTful flavors of your model.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to model you code after the domain.

As a rule of the thumb if field of an element has to be there for every valid entity then do not use Option.
If there are valid instances of an entity without that information use Option.

It helps to use `case classes` for that as you do not need to write val, get matchers and most scala serialization libraries work with the right out of the box.

Suggestion how to describe a book element:

```
case class Book(id: UUID, name: String, eTag: String)
```

Possible route:

```
POST /book/<name>
```

so as you set the other values yourself no need for a payload here.
And you only have a `Book` when the other values are given.